Determine legality of a path using std::filesystem under Windows?
In C++20, is it possible to check the legality of a path using std::filesystem under Windows?
By "legality", I mean whether the path contains any "forbidden" characters, is too long, or is otherwise syntactically incorrect?
Windows 11, Visual Studio 2022, C++20.

Check tooltip text on down button left of your question : This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Depends on your meaning of "forbidden". There's a difference between "filesystem disallows creating a file with a name containing a particular character" and (say) "the character is difficult/impossible for a user to create manually using the keyboard".   The first can be checked using filesystem (e.g. creation of file with specified characters will always fail, even if permissions, etc, on the containing folder otherwise allow creating the file).   The second means you need to check contents of the string representing the filename in addition to any checks done using filesystem.

@Pepijn Kramer: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful ". This is a dumb comment. Of course I did research before asking Stack Overflow. I don't see the point of quoting every document and Google search I read. And the question is clear, as witness two others understood it (I suspect you did also). As far as "useful", I, and many others, have a need to know this.

@Peter: You are right about filesystem, but I prefer not to open the file. Another respondent suggested opening the directory containing the file, which is a good idea.

@Woody20 I did not question your research, your question just did not indicate it.  Anyway, no std::filesystem does not have a function "out-of-the-box" where you can try without actually creating a file. The only solution is to write a small check function yourself.  See What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names? and I think max path length can be queried through the windows API. That should enable returning specific error info

The only reliable way to determine the validity of a path is to try opening it (or its parent directory, if you don't know if the target entity exists). The reason is that within a path, there can exist reparse points (redirections) of different types; they can take you to a filesystem with a different set of rules. I.e., the path valid in a straightforward analysis may become invalid in the real application.
Thus, when you attempt to open the entity referenced by a path, your request travels through different filesystem filters, can get redirected elsewhere (and/or sent across the network), reach the filesystem and get redirected again; and on each step, the check may succeed or fail.

Mayevski: I agree with your comment about multiple filesystems and filters. Unfortunately, I'd like to tell the user WHY a path is invalid, and there doesn't seem to be any way to do so. filesystem does not throw an exception on failure to open a file, contrary to the documentation I read, even on a "simple" situation: NTFS filesystem on a single Windows machine, no network, reparsing or redirection.

@Woody20 I am not aware of filesystem specifically, but enumerating a parent directory should do the job, and hopefully, you can get an error if this cannot be done. Otherwise, you would need to write functions that will analyze the volume name (there are 7-8 different formats there) and a path separately.
